# How to stop cannibalism because of a world's lack of resources?

Tags: biology, post-apocalypse, food

Create this mental picture in your head:
A World named Gazon that used to be full of life until the Sentient Gazons you created used up all the available resources and started eating each other. Only 20% of the original population has a Limited amount of resources and are **NOT** eating each other. How would those 20% stop the decreasing population?
Disclaimer: The Cannibalism is caused by lack of any other type of food.

**The Reason for Resource Exhaustion**

A few years ago on the planet Varon, another species (Varons) made by the Godlike beings got jealous of the resources because their world was as barren as this planet is now... the Varon species declared war on the other planet and exhausted its resources, causing the two planets to basically swap places.

**The Reason For Food Exhaustion**

During the war, the soil got acidic because of a weapon that shot acid across the world to damage the production of weapons for the species.

**Rules:**

- There is a blackmarket for seeds at expensive prices.
- There is also a lack of water.
- The soil is very acidic

**Question: Without intervention by the now-dorment Gods, how can the remaining population stabilize their numbers?**

Comment: It's not so much that it's bland as it isn't really specific or detailed enough. Why is there no food? If there isn't enough what do you want them to eat instead? What would keep the population in check if not this? etc.

Comment: Sorry about that i will edit it to be abit more specific

Comment: What happened to our good old carbon cycle? Usually dead release "resources" they kept for life, and then bacteria and plants recycle them all right.

Comment: To be honest im a not that good of a writer and dont really think about the complicated stuff Oof

Comment: I doubt it will be enough to keep it from closely, but I just did a *massive* edit on your question.  You are of course free to change back anything I got wrong or that you don't like.  I found a lot of it confusing, like why you name the now-gone planet/people that decimated your planet, but don't name your planet/people.  It puts the focus in the wrong place (it's not that I care about the names).

Comment: Thank you for tidying it up (sorry for not making it good from the start ;-;)

Comment: If cannibalism is caused by famine, people themselves would not be a good source of food because of emaciation. If food resources are not that scarce and cannibalism is just an "acquired taste", please reflect it in your question.

Comment: What's the relecance of cannibalism here? Does "cannibalism" imply "violent post-apocalyptic gangs", or "starving farmers who eat their dead"? What are the 20% non-cannibals eating? If there is no food other than people, why are they not starving? However, if there is food, just only enough for the 20%, then this becomes a simple question of "how can the best-positioned 20% reduce acidity, capture moisture, and breed acid-resistant plants, in a world where 80% are starving?" -- the cannibalism becomes irrelevant.

Comment: i guess it was stupid of me to even ask.

Comment: Cannibalism only works if there are people who have been fed one can kill and eat.  In a disaster people will tend to starve at about the same rate.  Cannibalism would work for the long term - centuries - if there are a group of magical people who don't need to eat and can  survive for generation after generation without human food and the non magical people who do need to eat hunt them for food.  But if all other sources of food are gone, cannibalism will keep the cannibals alive only as long as they can find live or recently dead people to eat, which could be only weeks or months.

Answer (score 4):

Just wait?

Like the trope of everyone in the world turning into Mad Max style murderous thieves, it's just not a feasible long-term occupation. Theres a risk each time you try to get new "resources" and you need to supplement your diet with a lot of extra food. I think it was 70% of the energy that is lost upon eating meat. So you either need to be killing several people a week to sustain a small group of people with risk to life and limb each time you try to kill or start reducing the amount of people you eat and replace the missing meat with other sources of food.

The full canibals will have to take greater risk each time to get their meat, and as the population drops there will be less targets so they will have the smallest communities with the greatest effort to stay alive. The partial cannibals will be able to have larger communities and are less threatened by the full cannibals. The non-cannibals have the largest communities and will gladly target and murder cannibals to secure themselves, which they most certainly can with their numbers.

Comment: True Thank you for your insight :)

Answer (score 0):

The non-cannibal types would have to be very well organized, disciplined, and defended, with the farms deep in their territory.

Wood ash and limestone would be a good way to reduce acidity of the soil where you wanted the main crops.

You would want to focus on plants with a high tolerance for acidic soil first, so that there would be less of a need to bring down the acidity initially....

[Here is a list](https://www.offthegridnews.com/survival-gardening-2/25-fruits-and-vegetables-to-grow-in-acidic-soil/)

Make your non-cannibalistic folks have strict punishment for cannibalism, and keep them well fed.  Attract more who want to give up cannibalism (plants don't fight back when you try to eat themn)

Make it very costly for the anyone to remain cannibalistic. by maintaining a perimeter, and expanding it as you increase the yield of your farmland... invite more people in, punish those who don't abide by the no-cannibalism laws, repeat.